# Concurrent proof method chaining with ability to pass arguments

Tags: javascript, class, concurrency

I have a class in which I am trying to add methods which will chain and add some extra logic to the other methods of the class, but I can't think of an optimal way of doing so. The main points I would like to cover sorted by priority:

1. It should not have a state attached to the main class so it can work without rare failures when running several methods of the same class concurrently
2. It should allow passing arguments in the chained function
3. It would be great to not create an extra class with each call.

What I have:

```js
const myApi = new MyApi();
myApi.foo(true); // true is the flag to enable some logic

export class MyApi {
  async foo(isSomeLogicEnabled) {
    if (isSomeLogicEnabled) {
      console.log('Some logic enabled');
    } else {
      console.log('Some logic disabled');
    }
  }
}
```

What I know is possible to do(It covers the point 1 and kinda covers the point 3, but I can't pass arguments with each call without hacks or without ruining the concurrency proofness):

```js
const myApi = new MyApi();
myApi.withSomeLogic().foo(); // Some logic enabled
myApi.foo(); // Some logic disabled

class MyApi {
  myApiWithSomeLogic;
  isSomeLogicEnabled = false;

  constructor(isSomeLogicEnabled) {
    this.isSomeLogicEnabled = isSomeLogicEnabled;

    if (!isSomeLogicEnabled) {
      this.myApiWithSomeLogic = new MyApi(true);
    }
  }

  withSomeLogic () {
    return this.myApiWithSomeLogic;
  }

  foo() {
    if (this.isSomeLogicEnabled) {
      console.log('Some logic enabled');
    } else {
      console.log('Some logic disabled');
    }
  }
}
```

What I would like to have:

```js
const myApi = new MyApi();
myApi.withSomeLogic(argsForSomeLogic).foo(); // Some logic enabled
myApi.foo(); // Some logic disabled
myApi.withSomeLogic(otherArgsForSomeLogic).foo(); // Some logic enabled

class MyApi {
  isSomeLogicEnabled = false;
  argsForSomeLogic;

  withSomeLogic (args) {
    return this; // With `isSomeLogicEnabled = this; and this.argsForSomeLogic = args` that won't affect other calls of the functions in the same class.
  }

  foo() {
    if (this.isSomeLogicEnabled) {
      console.log('Some logic enabled', argsForSomeLogic);
    } else {
      console.log('Some logic disabled');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't really have concurrency.

Comment: You will likely get what your after without using classes, functions & closures work well here.   No need for disabled / enabled features, as each function will return only features it can do.

Comment: @Pointy you look like someone with a lot of karma on reddit. Thanks for your help :P

Comment: Java has concurrency. You can start threads, and there are synchronization mechanisms. JavaScript does not.

Comment: @Pointy  Although to be fair, both can utilize threading. Especially now that JS has the SharedArrayBuffer,.  The main difference been synchronization on JS is message based, where as Java can use all the thread locking features.  But even then it's often a good option to use message queues for threading, I would anyway, never going back to Critical sections, and potential deadlocks, GPF's etc that often follow.. :)  From what I can tell in JS, Pages are processes, and webworkers are threads.

Comment: @Keith yes that is true, but the *basic* rule of JavaScript code is that synchronous code is purely synchronous. An infinite `while (true)` loop will not be interrupted (except by the hammer of the environment killing it). In a language like Java, that is not the case. Shared buffers, it is true, make it possible to see "reality" between what ultimately are concurrent threads. (Nothing in this question seems to be about "concurrency" anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

Javascript has very good support for doing what your after more functional.

Below is a example,..  Notice how you cannot do `myApi.foo()` because the method `foo` is only returned from `someLogic`, is also possible to pass args  even further down the tree, eg. `bar` has some extra parameters you can access on top of those provided by `someLogic`.   It's even possible for more levels, eg. `myApi.someLogic(arg).foo(arg).bar(args).zod(args)` etc.

`classes` these days are something I rearly use, and if you can get used to using functional coding you also prevent the oddies of `this` bindings.

```js
const MyApi = () => ({
  someLogic: (args) => ({
    foo: () =>
      console.log(`FooFN with args: ${args}`)
    ,
    bar: (args2) => 
      console.log(`BarFN ${args} - ${args2}`)    
  })
})



const myApi = MyApi();
myApi.someLogic('foo').foo();
myApi.someLogic('foo').bar('bar');

//just in case this is not obvious
//you don't need to pass the same params to each
const ml = myApi.someLogic('foo');
ml.foo();
ml.bar('bar2');
```

Comment: I need to use classes as a lot of argument juggling is happening and I am left with an option to use class, imitate the class behavior with functions or pass like 10 repeating arguments on each call.

Comment: This solution will work but it will basically be the same thing as if I do
`
  withSomeLogic (args) {
    return new MyAPI(args);
  }
`
Which I guess will be the solution after all.

Comment: @RobMinasyan  Not sure what you mean, there is no argument passing, as scope will keep the args up the tree.   Eg. look at `bar` in my example,  `args` is not passed down again, it's in scope so, `bar` gets `args2` and `args` with `args` not been passed down, the only arguments passed to `bar` where `args2`

Comment: @RobMinasyan  Also this creates the isolation you mentioned, eg. you cannot do `myApi().bar('bar')` only `myApi().someLogic('foo').bar('bar')`. no need for `isSomeLogicEnabled` boolean state.